# Use strict added to every file after Laravel Elixir upgrade - broken scripts

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I upgraded my Elixir and Gulp and right now I can see that some of my mixed scripts are broken.

When I hit `gulp` or `gulp --production` everything seems to be compiled, mixed and versioned fine. Problem is directly on the page. Scripts throw exceptions in the console.

Two broken scripts are right now `moment.js` and bootstrap `datetimepicker`.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'moment' of undefined(anonymous function) @ common-1e3de0f4.js:1(anonymous function) @ common-1e3de0f4.js:1
>       create:207
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

It must have something do to with the fact that I did npm update because all my custom scripts are fine - just these plugins are broken - while I haven't touched them.

I saw that every file is now preceded by **'use strict';** Previously it never happened before.

I really would like to solve it by myself but I have no idea where to start looking for a solution.

My gulpfile.js http://pastebin.com/NQ8f9tGr

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue, in fact Jeffrey is asking for feedback how people want to solve this, you can find more info [here](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/154) and give your opinion.

Also [quoting Jeffrey Way](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/154#issuecomment-107434252) on a possible solution:

> We have two options:
>
> 1. You may disable Babel support, if you don't desire it.
>      elixir.config.babel.enabled = false.
> 2. We can blacklist "useStrict", so
>      that it doesn't get included. Not sure we should do this, but it's an
>      option.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he replied to me: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/broken-mix-after-elixir-update